# Can an AppBar that opens a Drawer be positioned vertically on the left side of the application?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, toolbar, drawer, appbar

Currently I have an AppBar that is on the top of the page but I would like for it to be sticky on the left side and 100vh and would open the drawer onClick, (see image at bottom for desired look). This is using the code from Material-UI Persistent Drawer, https://material-ui.com/components/drawers/

I was able to change some css to get the effect I wanted, however it felt really messy and like there should be a less janky way of doing it.

Thank you in advance!

[This is the desired look of the AppBar in reference to the layout of the page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOtd3.png)